# Problems with CSS layout

Tags: html, css

I was wondering why my `Right-nav` div isn't responding to anything in the CSS.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="main-wrap">
        <div id="sidebarwrap">
        <div id="nav">Left Nav</div>
            advertisment pictures
        </div>
    <div id="content-wrap">
        <div id="picture-wrap">
        <div class="info">Picture</div>
        </div>
            <div id = "Content"><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p></div>
            <div class ="Right-nav"><p>right-nav</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
/**
 * custom layout
 */

#header,
#footer {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#main-wrap {
    background-color: #D9D9D9;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#sidebar {
    background-color: #d2d2d2;
}

#content-wrap {
    background-color: #c5c5c5;
}

.info {
    background-color: #DDD;
}
.info + .info {
    background-color: #e6e6e6
}


/* sizes */
#main-wrap > div {
    min-height: 450px;
}


#header,
#footer {
    min-height: 40px;
}

.info {
    min-height: 80px;
}

/* layout */

#main-wrap {
/* overflow to handle inner floating block */
    overflow: hidden;
}

#sidebarwrap {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:blue;
}

#nav{
    min-height: 80px;
    background-color: red;
}

#content-wrap {
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:blue;
}

#Content{
    float:left;
    width:40%;
    min-height:370px;
    background-color:red;
}

#Right-nav{
    background-color:red;
}

#picture-wrap {
/* overflow to handle inner floating block */
    overflow: hidden;
}

.info {
    width:100%;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you've given the right div a `class` in the HTML but an `id` in the CSS, change both to one or the other and the problem should be resolved.

Comment: Thanks it worked :). I needed a peer review, when it gets towards the end of the day I seem to simple some pretty stupid mistakes.

Comment: @AustinDavis That's fine happens to all of us at some point man!

Answer (score 2):

Change `<div class="Right-nav">` to `<div id="Right-nav">`

Comment: Thanks this is correct, sadly I'll have to get the answer to user1394965 since he/she posted first.